# C#: Do i need to Close my socket before destroying my object?

Tags: c#, sockets

I have a class where a socket is defined as a memberobject.
Does i need to .Close() the socket, if i want to destroy the object of this class (set to null)

Comment: Your class must implements `IDisposable` and close socket in the dispose method no need to set null.

Comment: If socket connection is open you must close it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I think you come from C++ side in C# Close method call in behind the dispose method. After Close you do not have to do anything. The object will be disposed and later from GC will be set to null.

but if you have a socket in your class as member you have to apply the Dispose pattern!

[Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)

And just dispose your socket in the dispose method of you created class see above the link.

```
public class DisposableResourceHolder : IDisposable {

  private Socket socket; // handle to a resource

  public DisposableResourceHolder(){
      this.socket= ... // allocates the resource
  }

  public void Dispose(){
      Dispose(true);
      GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
      if (disposing){
          if (socket!= null) socket.Dispose(); // HERE DISPOSE
      }
  }
}
```

Mark this as answer if this will solve your Problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes.

Ideally, your class will implement `IDisposable` which should close the socket. Not doing so means the socket object could persist in memory until the garbage collector gets it. If you plan to reconnect to the same endpoint you will have to, or else the underlying Windows libraries will throw an exception; (specifically Error 10056: A connect request was made on an already connected socket.)